# Tikz: Standard subgraph with n=5 without all edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I know there is a way of using "graphs.standard" and "subgraph k_n" to obtain a five node graph looking like a full star, like in the attached image.
[image]

But is there a possibility to tell LaTeX that I only want certain edges of it?
I want to explain adjacency lists and matrices on a beamer slide and only need some of them.

Do I need to draw the entire graph myself or can I tell LaTeX the edges I want?

Comment: Did any of the answers helped you? Please elaborate what is missing from the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a macro `\incomplete` that will do the work for you. The syntax is

`\incomplete[<radius>]{<num vertices>}{<edge list>}`

[image]

The two examples above are created with `\incomplete{5}{1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,2/4,2/5}` and `\incomplete{6}{1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/1,2/4}`

`<radius>` is optional. The default is `1.5cm`. `<edgelist>` is a comma-separated list with each entry of the form `vertex1/vertex2`. `<edgelist>` can be empty, e.g., `\incomplete{5}{}`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{vertex/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=1mm}}

\newcommand{\incomplete}[3][1.5cm]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{\node[vertex]at({90-360/#2*(\n-1)}:#1)(\n){\n};}
\foreach \v/\w in {#3}{\draw(\v)--(\w);}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\incomplete{5}{1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,2/4,2/5}\hspace{2cm}\incomplete{6}{1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/1,2/4}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By specifying that the graph is *simple*, one can modify the edges of a graph macro, and even remove them with the special `-!-` edge specification:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={circle,draw},simple] {
    subgraph K_n [n=5,clockwise];
    2 -!- 3 -!- 4 -!- 5 -!- 3;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: K5 with some edges removed]

[Link to the explanation in the docs](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/simple)